# 'void' type not allowed here java multiple class

Tags: types, void

```
class X
{
    private int A;
    private int B;
    public void setA(int A)
        {this.A=A;}
    public void setB(int B)
        {this.B=B;}
    public int getA( )
        {return this.A;}
    public int getB( )
        {return this.B;}
}    


class Z
{
    private X a;
    private X b;
    public void setZA(X a)
        {this.a=b;}
    public void setZB(X a)
        {this.b=b;}
    public X getZA()
        {return this.a;}
    public X getZB( )
        {return this.b;}
}

public class Start{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        Z z1= new Z();

        z1.setZA(z1.getZA().setA(11));
    }
}
```

i wanted to set private variable A of class X using public method public setZA()
of class Z.

i am just stuck in this problem.
can not figureout how to set the value and get it.

error :'void' type not allowed here

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: Start.java:6: error: 'void' type not allowed here
z1.setZA(z1.getZA().setA(11));
                                        ^

Comment: `setA` returns a Void type, then you're trying to pass that void into `setZA`. I can't recommend a fix though as I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: thank you very much sir.
i will try to explain,

A of class X is private. i have a member of class X named a in class Z.
i was trying to set the value of (a.A) using the setZA() function of class Z.

am i making it too complicated?

Comment: Why are you even calling `setZA` though? `z1.getZA().setA(11)` already does what you described your last comment. It's bad practice, and defeats the purpose of making `a` private, but it'll work.

Comment: thank you very much that solved the void error.
but if i try to print  z1.getZA().getA() it gives me "Nullpointer Exception" on the same line.

Comment: Because you never give `a` a value, so `getZA` returns `null`. You need to set it as a new X first before you can use it.